# Search Operators in RedditExtractoR

Tags: r

I'm trying to set up a process to pull down Reddit posts and comments relating to a group of keywords. The `get_reddit()` function in the `RedditExtractoR` package makes this extremely straightforward, but I'm not sure I'm using the search terms properly, and I haven't been able to find useful detail in the package documentation or online. I've also tested the search functions that work on the Reddit site, as below, with no luck.

Using the below code, I've tested a handful of terms, and the results are a bit confusing. (Note: in testing, the actual number of results may differ slightly based on the times when the queries are passed.)

```
library(RedditExtractoR)
term <- "bank" # or "bank loan" or "bank, loan" etc.
test <- get_reddit(search_terms = term,
                   page_threshold = 10,
                   sort_by = "new")
```

`"bank"` returns 196 records; `"loan"` gives 157. `"bank, loan"` and `"bank loan"` each give roughly 2700, however; `"bank OR loan"` gives just 31. I would expect `"bank, loan"`/`"bank loan"` to give no more than 196+157(=353).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that :

```
term <- "bank or loan"
```

is transformed to *bank+or+loan* and that could explain why you are getting unexpected result.  Check this line on [github](https://github.com/cran/RedditExtractoR/blob/master/R/RedditExtractoR.R#L26).

So I suggest you try something like this:

```
term <- "bank|loan"
```

Now I am getting approx 700 results.