# Extracting data in R using RedditExtracoR

Tags: r, reddit

I've tried to extract Reddit data in R using the following:

```
library(RedditExtractoR)
term <- "science" 
test <- get_reddit(search_terms = term,page_threshold = 10,sort_by = "new")
```

(taken from [Search Operators in RedditExtractoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099700/search-operators-in-redditextractor))

However, it gives me an emtpy data frame. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code with meanful content returned. Is the connected restricted on your side? (For others want to test, set `page_threshold = 1`, which makes it quicker.

Comment: ditto CodeGuy, I also get a 0 by18 dataframe

Comment: My connection does not have any restrictions that I know of, and this code does not return any connection errors. @user20650, yep, mine is 0x18

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu, I just tested this on PC, and it works (wheras it doesn't work on my Mac)

Comment: The problem for me was coming from reddit_content() function because it uses readLines(), which is known to have issues accessing web content on some systems

Comment: @CodeGuy, the successful run was on a Win10 as well. Not familiar with Mac.